# add comma for sentence with two verbs with one object?

Tags: verbs, commas

Should "and follow" be between commas in the following sentence?

"A person must pledge allegiance to and follow him."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a RNR (Right Node Raising) construction.  The analysis is disputed, but Postal and, following him, Ross, propose a structure:

```
    A person must [pledge allegiance to [GAP]] and [follow [GAP]] him.
```

Since GAPs generally cause intonation breaks ("comma" intonation), then, yes, there should be commas where the gaps are.